# Show ErrorMsg if input-box is empty

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

1. How can i check my Input, if this is empty, then show an Error-Msg.
2. How Should i add delete function to my Delete btn?

   import React, {useState} from 'react';
   import {Button, Input} from "antd";

   export default function List ({items, setItems}){

   ```
   const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');

   const AddButtonClick = () => {
       const inputCheck = document.getElementsByClassName('addItemInput').length;
       if (inputCheck === ""){
           alert("Test");
           return false
       } else {

           const newItem ={
               itemName: inputValue,
           };

           const newItems = [...items,newItem];

           setItems(newItems);
           setInputValue('');
       }

   }

   return(
       <>

           <Input value={inputValue} onChange={(event) =>
               setInputValue(event.target.value)}
                  name='input'
                  className='addItemInput'
                  placeholder="Artikel hinzufügen"
           />

           <Button
               type="primary"
               className='btn'
               onClick={() => AddButtonClick()}
           >Hinzufügen</Button>

       </>
   )
   ```

   }

Comment: What do you mean by "check my input"? If you want to look at the value of your input component, simply use the "inputValue" variable.
If I'm misunderstanding you and you're trying to do something more complex, maybe take a look at useRef: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

Comment: How should i use inputValue ?

Comment: What do you mean? Just do inputValue === ""

Comment: THANK YOU. :) you can write this and i check it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To preform operations on the current value on an input, you can preform the opperation on the varible you feed into the "value" property. In this case, compare the value stored in the "inputValue" varible by doing: `inputValue === ""`.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to check the element's value

```
const inputCheck = document.getElementsByClassName('addItemInput').value;
    if (inputCheck === ""){
        alert("Test");
        return false
    }
...
```

Don't know about the delete button as you really haven't provided any helpful context.

Comment: I have also tried this but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementsByClassName will get all element that class equal "addItemInput",

try this.

```
const inputCheck = document.getElementsByClassName('addItemInput')[0].value;
    if (inputCheck === ""){
        alert("Test");
        return false
    }
...
```